# When R(v3.2.5) launched then the error occur "unable to load shared object" on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

After I installed R v3.2.5 on ubuntu 12.04 (64bit), launch R on command line, I can see error like this:

```
***
R version 3.2.5 (2016-04-14) -- "Very, Very Secure Dishes"
Copyright (C) 2016 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

**Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) :
  unable to load shared object '/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so':
  libm.so.11835d88: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
During startup - Warning message:
package ‘stats’ in options("defaultPackages") was not found**
***
```

And I can find same error when I install some package. How can I resolve this one?

And I add some information about stats.so

```
R# R CMD ldd /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
/usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so: /usr/local/lib64/libgfortran.so.3: version `GFORTRAN_1.4' not found (required by /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf)
        linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffb75f6000)
        liblapack.so.3gf => /usr/lib/liblapack.so.3gf (0x00007f9cdef48000)
        libblas.so.3gf => /usr/lib/libblas.so.3gf (0x00007f9cdecca000)
        libgfortran.so.3 => /usr/local/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 (0x00007f9ccec89000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9cce98c000)
        libR.so => /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so (0x00007f9cce3bf000)
        libgomp.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007f9cce1b2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9ccdf94000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9ccdbd6000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f9ccd9c1000)
        libm.so.11835d88 => not found
        libc.so.11835d88 => not found
        libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007f9ccd77e000)
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9ccd540000)
        liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007f9ccd31e000)
        libbz2.so.1.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007f9ccd10e000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9cccf05000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9cccd01000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9cdf9a3000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f9cccad9000)
```

Comment: I solve this error finally.
1. findout where this missing .so file located in my linux
2. copy that library and then paste it in /usr/local/lib64/
3. if there are several same type error occured, then doing same method

thank you for editting my question and giving comment how to use this site.

Comment: You may want to post this as an answer. Then you can accept it, so there's no need of editing your title.

Comment: Your system must be in *severe* trouble as the `stats.so` shared library _is part of the very `r-base-core`_ package as the `R` command.  But if you are in the habit of semi-randomly moving shared libraries, all bets are off.  If I were you, I'd read [the Ubuntu README on CRAN](http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu) and get myself a properly built and maintained _current_ binary of R for your Ubuntu flavour. (Oh, but not for 12.04 which you should really upgrade from. 14.04 is fine; 16.04 is better.)

Comment: @Kyll: Gosh, no, he already did and was told not to.  Besides, that's no "answer" but a poor man's band-aid patch.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Er, which _is_ still an answer. An answer could also be "Your entire structure is borked, reinstall the whole thing".

Comment: @Kyll: I have no bone in that fight; I am merely telling you that a) someone already suggested the opposite of what you advovate and b) that OP followed through with that.   He answered 2 hours ago; the comment came 40 mins ago.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel: That's right. I agree with  your idea. I do not want to mess my system. I will read recommended README and make my system comportable.

Comment: @Kyll : Thank you for your advice. This is my first question on stackoverflow. Next using would be fine~

Answer (score 0):

According to DirkEddelbuettel's advice, I removed r-base from my linux(ubuntu 12.04) and .so files that I copied from other packages in my machine. Then I  reinstalled r-base with the guide "[UBUNTU PACKAGES FOR R](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/)".

In a process of my previous installation, there is no step of installing supported packages (dependency packages) of r-base package.

This is the command.

```
sudo apt-get build-dep r-base
```

After installation of this recommended bundles, there was no error for launching R console.